# PrestaShop save HTML in CustomerMessage->message

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm making a customization in a PrestaShop 1.6.0.14 where I need to offer an HTML editor when the employee answers to a customer thread. This part I achieved and the I'm getting to send the HTML in the e-mail message.

My problem is to show in the history, I need to show the HTML in the history (sometimes employees send links etc..). To achieve that I need to be able to save HTML in the `message` field of the `customer_message` table. When I go to the definition of the ObjectModel (`classes/CustomerMessage.php`) I see this:

```
'message' =>            array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required' => true, 'size' => 65000),
```

Which is cleaning the HMTL. So I created a new file at `override/classes/CustomerMessage.php` with this content:

```
class CustomerMessage extends CustomerMessageCore
{

    public function __construct($id = null) {
        self::$definition['fields']['message'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'validate' => 'isAnything', 'required' => true, 'size' => 65000);

        parent::__construct($id);
    }

}
```

This I believe that would override the property allowing me to save HTML in this field. But it doesn't work. Am I doing it the wrong way? If so, how can I redefine this field?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use this settings:

```
self::$definition['fields']['message'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml', 'required' => true, 'size' => 65000);
```

the type should be TYPE_HTML, and don't change validation `isCleanHtml` because it check about parts of html code that you don't want (like js, script, iframe, etc)

Let me know :)

PS: Every time that we make an override, delete the `class_index.php` that is stored in `cache` folder

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I remember you answering a lot of my questions =]. It didn't work, it seems that the override is not working, I put a die() in the method and it doesn't stop the execution

Comment: Have you removed the `class_index.php` in the `cache` folder? Are you sure that the text isn't saved in html? Because in the backoffice the visualization is 'cleaned'.

Comment: Yeah.. it was just cache! Thanks for the help! Just to enrich the thread for future readers, you can do this way too (step 2) http://nemops.com/adding-new-fields-to-prestashop-contact-form/#.WO0izVMrKF0

Comment: Perfect, I'm glad to hear that :)